# For loop to print the number in sequence and reverse it

Tags: java

How to print the following output with only one for-loop in java?

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Code snippet:

```
class Series{

public static void main(String args[]){

    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){

         System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println(i);

    for(int j=9; j>=0; j--){

         System.out.println(j);        
   }          
}
```

My program's in the following manner. Can anyone correct it?

Comment: hmmm i think your code has an infinite loop in it and never stops printing out values

Comment: It doesn't compile either. Your syntax on the second loop is incorrect.

Comment: let correct it and give me output

Comment: change for(int j=9; j>=0; j++){ to for(int j=9; j>0; j--){
Work well...

Answer (score 11):

```
public static void main(String...strings ){
    int dir = 1;
    for(int i=1; i>0; i+=dir){
        if(i == 10) 
            dir = -1;
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: How to implement this for infinitive loop?

Answer (score 2):

The series in the question is wrong.

It should be: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 **7 6 5 4 3 2 1**

The code, in one loop, is as follows:

```
int ctr = 1;
for(int i = 1; i > 0; i += ctr)
{
    if(i == 10) 
    {
        ctr = -1;
    }
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: how can we do it recursively?.

Answer (score 1):

Every sequence follows a pattern, Let's try finding one in this.

To work with this code, analyze What loop would print with the **variable** that you **increment** and What you want in the output?

In your problem, assuming that the number you are entering is entered by user i.e. **n**, you want 2*n - 1 numbers in your sequence. Hence we now have the limits of our loop

For n=5, Under no Conditions the loop would simply print a sequence like this

**1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9** provided you are starting your loop from 1.

The sequence you want is **1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1**.

Now looking at both the sequences you can see that the sequence is same till the mid point that is till the value of n is reached. Now if you observe the pattern further if you subtract **2 from 6 you get 4** that is the number you want in your sequence. Similarly when you **subtract 4 from 7 you get 3** which is the next number in the sequence you required.

Hence the pattern this sequence follows is that after the loop reaches the value provided by the user you need to subtract (2 * k) from the next number where **k starts from 1 and increases with every iteration**

Now you know how to achieve the pattern which would be easy to achieve using conditional statements.

PS: let's assume an added constraint of using no conditional statements then we have to write an arithmetic expression to solve our problem.

Following the pattern again the expression must display **i** where i is the variable incremented in the loop

so our code looks like

```
for (i = 1; i<=2*n - 1;i++)
{
   System.out.print(i);
}
```

Now to get the pattern we need to subtract multiples of 2 after the user provided integer **n** is reached. But whatever we subtract should also not affect out first n integers.

Since we know we have to subtract multiples of 2 we know the expression we have to subtract would look like **2 * (____)**. As we want a sequence of multiples we can obtain that using **%**. As soon as the number goes over n the **%** operator on i would give us back sequence from 0 to n-1 hence generating multiples of 2.

Now our expression comes to **2 * (i % n)**. But the problem is that it would also subtract from the first 4 integers which we don't want so we have to make changes such that this expression will work only after loop reaches the value provided by the user.

As we know the division **/** operator provides us with the quotient. Hence it would yield us 0 till we reach the value of user defined number and 1 for the rest of the sequence as we run our loop till 2*n -1. Hence multiplying this expression to our previous expression yields **2*(i%n)*(i/n)**

And there we have it our final code to generate the sequence would be

```
for (int i = 1;i<2*r;i++)
{
  System.out.print(i - 2 * (i%r)*(i/r));
}
```

Observe the above code for the first n-1 integers i/r would make subtracted expression 0 and for i = n, **i % r** would make the expression 0. For the rest of the sequence **i / r** would generate value 1 and hence we will get multiples of 2 from **2 *( i % r)** to provide us with the sequence

Comment: How can we do this recursively

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 int j = 10;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        if(i<10)
        System.out.print(" " +i);
        if(i==10){
            i--;                
            System.out.print(" " +j);

            if(j==1){
                i++;
            }
            j--;
        }
    }
```

**OutPut**

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        if((i/10)%2 == 0)
            System.out.print(i%10 + " ");
        else
            System.out.print((10-(i%10)) + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, You just need a if condition in for loop.

```
        int i = 1;
        for(int j=1; j<=20; j++)
        {
            if(j<11)
             System.out.print(j+" ");
            else
            {
                System.out.print((j - i ==  10 ?" ": (j-i + " ")));
                i = i+2;
            }
       }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class forLoopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

        for (int j = 10; j >= 1; j--) {

            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Output : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: OP asks for a way to have just **one** `for` loop; your code is just the original one with minor changes in the starting values and loop conditions.